# Simple question about propagation of error/uncertainty

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, error-analysis, statistics

> I'm stuck on a seemingly simple question about propagation of error. Say we repeatedly measure the speed of a particle, and we estimate the uncertainty in the measured speed to be 10 percent. What is the uncertainty in the kinetic energy of the particle? (Uncertainty in mass is negligible.)
>
> (This was a physics GRE practice question. The answer is 20 percent.)

The formula I know for propagation of error is, for $f = AB$,

$$\left( \frac{\sigma_f}{f}\right)^2 = \left( \frac{\sigma_A}{A}\right)^2 +  \left( \frac{\sigma_B}{B}\right)^2 .$$

So, if I'm correct that uncertainty is defined $\left( \frac{\sigma_f}{f}\right)$, it follows that

$$\Delta KE = \sqrt{2} \Delta v$$

where $\Delta KE$ is uncertainty in kinetic energy and $\Delta v$ is uncertainty in speed. But this gives $14$ percent. Could somebody point out my error?

Comment: That's only true if $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated.  Presumably you're letting $A$ and $B$ both represent speed, in which case they are *perfectly* correlated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, your equation holds only if $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated.  More generally, if $F$ is a function of uncorrelated variables $A$ and $B$, then

$$(\delta F)^2 = \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}\delta A\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial B} \delta B\right)^2$$

If you plug in $F=AB$, then you find that
$$ \left(\delta F\right)^2 = (B\cdot \delta A)^2 + (A \cdot \delta B)^2$$
or
$$ \left(\frac{\delta F}{F}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\delta A}{A}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\delta B}{B}\right)^2 $$

In your case, $A$ and $B$ are the same, so they are the exact *opposite* of uncorrelated.  In your case, the appropriate thing to do would be to consider $F$ to be a function of a single variable, and simply let

$$\delta F = \left|\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}\right| \delta A$$
$$\frac{\delta F}{F} = \left|\frac{1}{F}\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}\right| \delta A$$

---

To answer the question at a deeper level, we model experimentally measured quantities as continuous random variables, with our experimental uncertainties corresponding to their standard deviations.

Let $X$ be a random variable with expected value $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mu_X$ and variance $Var(X)\equiv \mathbb{E}\big[ (X-\mu_X)^2\big]=\sigma_X^2$, and let $g$ be a function of $X$.  We can expand $g$ in a Taylor series around $\mu_X$:

$$g(X) = g(\mu_x) + g'(\mu_X)\cdot (X-\mu_X) + \frac{1}{2}g''(\mu_X) (X-\mu_X)^2 + \ldots $$

Truncating after the linear term, we write

$$g(x) = g(\mu_X) + g'(\mu_X)\cdot (X-\mu_X)$$

We can now calculate the mean and variance of $g$:

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = g(\mu_X) + g'(\mu_X)\mathbb{E}[X-\mu_X] = g(\mu_X) + g'(\mu_X)\cdot (\mu_X-\mu_X) = g(\mu_X)$$
$$Var(g(X)) = \mathbb{E}\big[\big(g(X)-g(\mu_X)\big)^2\big] = \big(g'(\mu_X)\big)^2 \cdot \mathbb{E}\big[(X-\mu_X)^2\big] = \left(\frac{dg}{dX}\cdot \sigma_X\right)^2$$

This is where the single-variable error propagation formula comes from.  But now, consider a function $F$ of two variables $X$ and $Y$, with respective means $\mu_X,\mu_Y$ and variances $\sigma_X^2,\sigma_Y^2$, and *covariance*

$$Cov(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}\big[(X-\mu_X)\cdot(Y-\mu_Y)\big]$$

We Taylor expand $F$ to linear order:

$$F(X,Y) = F(\mu_X,\mu_Y) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(X-\mu_X) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y} (Y-\mu_Y) $$

Repeating the earlier steps, the mean of $F$ is

$$\mathbb{E}\big[F(X,Y)\big] = F(\mu_X,\mu_Y) $$

The variance, however, develops a slight subtlety.  Notice that

$$\left(F(X,Y)-F(\mu_X,\mu_Y)\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\right)^2(X-\mu_X)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\right)^2(Y-\mu_Y)^2 + 2\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)$$

It follows that

$$Var\big(F(X,Y)\big) = \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial X} \sigma_X\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\sigma_Y\right)^2 + 2\frac{\partial F}{\partial X} \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y} Cov(X,Y)$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, then $Cov(X,Y)=0$, and so we get our nice simple formula again.  However, if $Cov(X,Y)\neq 0$, we need to take it into account.

Answer (score 2):

Your rule works for multiplication and division of independent uncertainties not raised to any interesting powers.  The more general rule is

$$
(\mathrm d f)^2 = 
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial A} \mathrm dA
\right)^2
+
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial B} \mathrm dB
\right)^2
+ \cdots
$$

If the terms in the sum were linear rather than added in quadrature, this would just be the total derivative of $f$; adding in quadrature accounts for the fact that *uncorrelated* errors are not likely to all contribute in the same direction.

You have, with the usual kinetic energy $K=\frac12 mv^2$,

\begin{align}
(\mathrm dK)^2 &= \left(
\frac{\partial K}{\partial v} \mathrm dv
\right)^2 + \text{negligible}^2
\\
\mathrm dK
&=
mv\ \mathrm dv
= \frac{2K}{v} \mathrm dv
\\
\frac{\mathrm dK}{K} &= 2\frac{\mathrm dv}{v}
\end{align}

The factor of two arises because $v$ is squared.

Comment: Why did you write negligible? I see that that there is no B term, so instead of writing zero you wrote negligible. Can you please elaborate on that part?

Comment: There is a "B" term: the mass.  You said the uncertainty in the mass was negligible.  So the answerer is following your lead.